# How to improve dereferencing of smart pointer that is a member variable of class

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have the following class structure -

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Inner> InnerPtr;
class Outer {
   private:
      const InnerPtr ptr_;

   public:
      Outer(const InnerPtr& ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {} 
      int calculate(int id) {
           return ptr_->calculate_other(id);
      }
}
```

Here, `Outer::calculate()` is likely to be called a lot of times (in ordered of millions).

Since each call to `Outer::calculate()` dereferences `ptr_`, I think it would have a performance impact compared to just using the object.

So I came up with this -

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Inner> InnerPtr;
class Outer {
   private:
      Inner& obj_;    // to reference *ptr_
      const InnerPtr ptr_;  // still need to hold a copy of smart pointer to ensure obj stays in memory during the lifetime of Outer
      
   public:
      Outer(const InnerPtr& ptr) : ptr_(ptr), obj_(*ptr) {} 
      int calculate(int id) {
           return obj.calculate_other(id);
      }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution. I'm looking for suggestions to improve the `calculate` function.

NOTE: Assume that `ptr` passed to `Outer()` is a non-null share pointer

Comment: _"I think it would have a performance impact"_ I strongly recommend testing this assumption before acting on it.

Comment: First benchmark and profile your whole program. Optimize the top two (or possibly three) bottle-necks and benchamrk/profile again. Do this a *couple* of times, tops, and your performance should be "good enough". And I doubt you would come to pointer derefencing optimizations likes this anywhere in your optimization passes.

Answer (score 1):

A reference is typically implemented as a pointer at the hardware level in C++, when it cannot be removed entirely (because logically it is an alias).  Removing a reference from the body of a class is very difficult; I am unaware of a compiler that tries (other than possibly eliminating the class instance entirely in some cases).

The difference between following a `Inner const&` and a `shared_ptr<Inner const>const` in terms of generated assembly is going to be basically nothing.

Now, you misunderstand how `const` works; `const InnerPtr` is a const pointer to a non-const value, while `const Inner&` is a reference to a const value.  But I expect that is not intentional.

Now, a `Foo&` is analogous to a `Foo* const`, so that *top level* `const` could lead to some optimizations somehow; you are not allowed to change where either point.  And that *could* lead to a compiler being able to prove that a `Foo&` refers to the same object in two bits of code and not be able to prove that a `Foo*` does.

However, in your example, you had a `const shared_ptr`, which also has top-level `const`.

As a general rule, premature optimization is the root of all evil.  But so is premature pessimization (the opposite of optimization).  Following a smart pointer is not premature pressimization, and your reference optimization is an example of premature optimization.  You should only consider making this kind of change when you have already identified a performance bottleneck there.

---

You are honestly more likely going to run into problems caused by the extraneous reference count increase in the constructor when you build the `Outer` class from an rvalue shared ptr, than the problem you identify.  What more, that extra atomic reference count is going to be a diffuse slowdown, in that atomic operation synchronization doesn't cause most of its slowdown at the point the code runs, but rather in trashing the CPU cache and making the rest of the program slower.

So change this:

```
explicit Outer(InnerPtr ptr) : ptr_(std::move(ptr)) {}
```

to remove the pessimization; now:

```
Outer outer( GenerateInnerPtr() );
```

does 1 less reference count increase and decrease than it did before, and no other case results in more reference count increase/decrease.

Answer (score 1):

First:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming

is an important quote, because most often, people have false understandings what makes a program slow and what fast.

Second:
Lets assume the indirect makes your program slower. Then biggest question is: Do you need the indirection? Your questions lacks a clear answer to this. Is lifetime management or object polymorphism the reason? I strongly assume that if you can make these optimization you had in mind, you can eliminate the indirection altogether.

Third:
Much more important I would assume is if the compiler is able to inline all the calculate function calls. So it would also be important how your definition of the inner class looks like. Thats one of the reason to always post a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Fourth:
If you still really care about performance profile your program and might also use https://godbolt.org/ .

Update, Fifth:
I forgot to mention: Algorithmic complexity is usually the bigger issue with bad performance, meaning: Do you loop several times? Are your loops nested? Can you calculate it before or when creating? Can you cache values?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Probably not. As long as you use an optimiser, indirecting through a reference is just as expensive as indirecting through a shared pointer, so you aren't necessarily saving anything, while you're paying by making the class non-assignable, and being simply larger by storing the address twice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no improvement from caching a reference to the `Inner` object since on all existing implementations references are implemented as pointers. Basically, you just duplicated the pointer that is part of `shared_ptr` already and increased size of `Outer` object.

Unless you are able to cache `Inner` directly as member of `Outer`, or at least some important subset of its data, there is little you can do. You have to rethink the design of the `Inner` and `Outer` classes and whether it is possible to merge them.

Another point to think about is whether it is possible to optimize memory access patterns of your code. For example, if there is a list of `Outer` objects, over which you call `calculate`, the accesses to `Inner` objects may be unpredictable if each `Inner` object is allocated separately. You may improve performance if these objects are allocate linearly in a contiguous buffer (e.g. in a `vector` of by using a custom memory allocator).

And of course, as others have recommended, you should profile your code to see whether this code is actually is a bottleneck and whether any changes do in fact improve performance.

Comment: _"all ... references are implemented as pointers"_ this is often true, but not always.

Comment: @DrewDormann Do you have an example where this is not true? On what compiler and platform?

Comment: Sure!  :)  Here are two different non-pointer implementations that could be expected on any compiler or platform.  https://godbolt.org/z/Pca6dY

Comment: @DrewDormann What you see there is a result of compiler optimizations. Of you specify -O0 you will see that the compiler calculates and stores pointers on the stack in both cases. This kind of optimizations doesn't work with data members though. And it doesn't mean that references have a different implementation on that compiler - they still are effectively pointers.